# Bash Pass variable to grep

Tags: bash

I've got a problem with passing variable to grep. It's always returning 0. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
tests="some text"
found=$(grep "$tests" /file.conf | wc -l)
echo "$found"
```

found is always 0 when called this way. When calling directly

```
 found=$(grep "some text" /file.conf | wc -l)
```

it's returning for example 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of the script and make sure the calls look correct, etc.

Comment: This code works for me. The only thing I can see is that in the example they operate on different files.

Comment: To clarify; on my debian system this returns the number 4: tests="deb http" ; found=$(grep "$tests" /etc/apt/sources.list | wc -l) ; echo "$found"

Comment: It could be that `$tests` is a local variable and not visible in the `$(...)` subshell, but that's not happening for me. On my ubuntu, bash-4.3.30 it works either way. Another debug technique is to `tee` to a temp file while debugging, e.g., `found=$(grep "$tests" file | tee /tmp/tmp.txt | wc -l)`

Comment: This probably goes without saying but, "some text" is actually in /file.conf, right? Also, is /file.conf and /opt/nsnras/conf/sockd.conf the same file?

Comment: If your script file has CR+NL line endings, then `"$tests"` ends with a `\r` character. Run `dos2unix` on your script file.

Comment: It works here.  Another possible issue is the location of the file - /file.conf is at the root directory, are there any permission issues?  Perhaps you can try running the same command set on a file in your home directory?

Comment: It was problem with line endings as glenn wrote. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
found=$(grep "some text" /file.conf | wc -l)
```

to

```
found=$(grep -c "some text" /file.conf)
```

:)
Dale